# Read More link for each post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using wordpress . i want to add read more link for each post automatically. i dont want to use  tag . As i want to keep length og each post same. like after 200 words it will show read more link.

I am using twenty ten theme . i put code in function.php

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read the Rest...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

But this is not working .

Any body have idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the_content instead of the_excerpt

if all fails try to set $more = 0; before your loop starts